# convert code from win form to devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

This code use with code of win form.So I want to use it with DevExpress and the problem is I don't know which tool in DevExpress that I can use instead of this code.I have a class below: Thanks

```
using System.Drawing;
using System;

namespace Extender
{

public class MenuItem : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
{

    private string _Command;

    public string Command
    {
        get
        {
            return _Command;
        }
        set
        {
            _Command = value;
        }
    }

    private object _Argument;

    public object Argument
    {
        get
        {
            return _Argument;
        }
        set
        {
            _Argument = value;
        }
    }

    private Int16 _ModuleID;

    public Int16 ModuleID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ModuleID;
        }
        set
        {
            _ModuleID = value;
        }
    }

   public      MenuItem()
    {
    }

 public     MenuItem(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

  public       MenuItem(string text, EventHandler onclick) :
                this(text)
        {
            this.Click += onclick;
        }
    }
}
```

And the code below is the method that I use to create menu from database using entity framework with winform

```
private void LoadMenus(ToolStripItemCollection Menu,string ParentName)
    {

        using (var ctx = new CambbusEntities())
        {

            foreach (var obj in ctx.view_ObjectDetails.Where(a => a.ObjectType == "MENU" && a.ParentName==ParentName &&a.LanguageID == Cambbus.Properties.Settings.Default.LanguageID ).OrderBy(a=>a.SortOrder))
            {

                string mText = obj.ObjectText;
                string nName = obj.ObjectName;
                if (mText == "-")
                    continue;
                Extender.MenuItem m = new Extender.MenuItem(mText);
                m.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Left;
                //m.Text = obj.ObjectText;
                //m.Name = obj.ParentName;
                m.ModuleID = (Int16)obj.ModuleID;
                m.Command = obj.Command;
                m.Argument = obj.Argument;
                m.Image = App.GetImageByEntity((obj.ImageTag)+"");

                if (m.Command!=""){
                    m.Click += DynamicMenuClick;
                }
                bool Is4Perm = obj.ModuleID > 0;
                if(Is4Perm){
                    m.Enabled = CurrentUser.CanViewModule((Int16)obj.ModuleID);
                }
                Int16 shortcutNum = ((Int16)(obj.ShortcutNum));
                if (shortcutNum != 0)
                {
                   m.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)(Keys.Control)) | ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)(shortcutNum));
                }
                Menu.Add(m);
                LoadMenus(m.DropDownItems,nName);

            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is I don't know the properties of DevExpress that can use instead winform. So can I use DevExpress instead of winform? 
[this is my image of winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd59j.jpg)
and I want to change to DevExpress same as in picture [DevExpress Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUrhu.jpg) by using my class and method.thanks

Comment: Please add an image to illustrate what UI you have. I'll update my answer to describe what BarItems you need.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress bars have several types of menu item. Their list is available at [The List of Bar Items and Links](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2511). Since you need to handle a click on an item, I think you need [BarButtonItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarButtonItemtopic). You can set its caption by using the [BarButtonItem.Caption](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarButtonItem_Captiontopic) property. For a click, handle the [BarItem.ItemClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItem_ItemClicktopic) event.

**Edited**

With DevExpress, you can replace the orange tool bar with a [Bar](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBartopic). For this, simply place [BarManager](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarManagertopic) on your form. It creates some default bars. Program, Sales, Help, etc. commands can be replaced with BarButtonItems as I described above. Listings and its sub items can be done by using [BarSubItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarSubItemtopic). I see that you have the Windows item. If your application is MDI, I suggest you use [BarMdiChildrenListItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarMdiChildrenListItemtopic). It will automatically generate items for all MDI child forms.

If you need to generate items in code, refer to the [BarManager Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarManagertopic) help topic that provides some code for this.

Comment: @Ley Does it work for you? If so, make my answer as a solution to close this thread.

Comment: Now I try to find the property in DevExpress that can use instead of System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownItem and ToolStriptItemCollection

Comment: @Ley I suggest you edit your question to include all relevant information on what you need to resolve. Also attach an image to illustrate what layout you have now. The best way to get appropriate help is to give as much information as you have in your question.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help

Comment: Yes now I can change from winform to use DevExpress with some tool like  what you tell me.Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ley Please mark my answer as a solution to this thread will be resolved.